# How to bring two arrows together towards the number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a system that people can up/down vote. I have two arrows, and between the arrows there's a number. Just like Stack OVerflow and Reddit. Only problem is my arrows are too far apart from the number. I tried padding/height/ every thing I could think of but none of them works. They are all in a table, so if I mess up the whole table size gets messed up. Here's my full code.

```
<table class="table">
    {% if posts %}
      {% for post in posts %}
        <tr id="cell">
          <td class="vert-align">
          <div>
            <a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=1" class="vote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <br />

<span class="number" style="height:1px; font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
"><h4 id="vote_count_{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.get_vote_count }}</h4></span>     <br>

<a href="/post/{{ post.slug }}/vote?is_up=0"  class="vote">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
          </td>
```

I have more cells below.

this is my css.

```
.table #cell .vert-align a .glyphicon{
  font-size: 1em;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0em;
}
h4{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Also if anyone can tell me what's wrong with my js file I would be appreciated. I'm trying to make when user clicks the arrow the arrow to change the color and stay changed untill I click that arrow or the other arrow. sorry if it doesn't make sense I'm trying to make it (like stack-overflow and reddit) right now, when I click the arrow it changes the color but as soon as I click something else, like an empty space on my web the color gets changed.

```
function vote(node) {
    var thread_id = node.attr("href").split('\/')[2];
    $.ajax({
        url: node.attr("href"),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#vote_count_"+thread_id).html(data.count);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data.responseJSON.error_message);
        }
    });
}

$("a.vote").on("click", function() {
    vote($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you post some of the generated HTML? Preferably as a snippet. Code like the above is very hard to test, because I don't have the data to work with.

Comment: WRT the Javascript, I'm not sure what comes out of the ajax call, but you will need a permanent change, for instance to the class of the arrow, which you then can address in CSS. E.G. give an unvoted arrow `class="vote"`, and a voted one `class="vote isvoted"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative positioning in the style sheet to position the arrows

```
position: relative; left: -5px;
```